# How to add methods to a class without changing the COM+ Class ID

Tags: c#, com, coding-style

I am writing some code in a dll that must conform to certain specs. One of those, is that it can only use the methods, enums, classes, etc that it currently has.

The specification of all one method is enforced by an application that I "submit" the dll to. If it doesn't conform to the specs, it rejects it.

Update: This is specifically happening in C#. The documentation regarding the spec states: "If any code other than the four public functions is changed, the COM+ Class ID could change and the object safety script will not work, causing the BSTCustomValidation.dll validation component to not run."

Comment: Can you write a wrapper class that serves as interface instead? Have the application validate the usage of the one method in this interface, which in its turn calls every method from the class behind it in the order you need.

Comment: What crude requirement is that? I cannot believe that you are forced to Forget good coding practices? Or does the requirement really mean "one EXPORTED method"? Then do that: export 1 and do not export the other 19. The app will only see the exported method.

Comment: If you're trying to not break or add to the public API, then the visibility of your methods as private/protected/internal as appropriate.

Comment: Have you considered declaring delegates and re-using them throughout your method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you should [define an explicit interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fcadw4a.aspx).

> Because COM interop generates a class interface automatically, post-version changes to your class can alter the layout of the class interface exposed by the common language runtime. Since COM clients are typically unprepared to handle changes in the layout of an interface, they break if you change the member layout of the class.

Combining that with declaring everything `private` or `internal` as necessary should be sufficient.

Comment: this worked perfectly. I hope you or someone else can post some links about what's going on exactly here and how this relates to the COM+ Class ID, but it seems to be that the class ID is entirely dependent on the "signature" of the class and not the code per-se

Comment: @TruthOf42 - Truth be told, I knew nothing about COM object IDs before I started researching this question, so I wouldn't be able to explain why it works the way it does.  I would definitely be interested in knowing the why as well.  Ask a new question?

Comment: fyi: stackoverflow.com/questions/19190327/how-is-the-com-class-id-determined

Answer (score 8):

Given the requirement is to only have one **exported** function then it is easy to fulfill that by **not exporting the other 19.**

Comment: maybe this should be moved to stackoverflow, but do you know how to do it in C#, I don't actually give any method or class a export attribute

Comment: You should have mentioned the word "assembly" somewhere => Use the internal (or protected, private) keyword. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b(v=vs.90).aspx  By the way: Do you know how the one-method-test is performed? Via reflection?

Comment: @JensG - I'd suggest editing that into the question.

Comment: I had already made them private, to no avail. See my update about  the "Com+ Class ID" from the documentation