# How is the Com+ Class ID determined?

Tags: c#, interface, com

related to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189061/how-to-add-methods-to-a-class-without-changing-the-com-class-id/19189063?noredirect=1#comment28393838_19189063) question:

I had a C# template/project that I had to put in some customized code into. The documentation said "If any code other than the four public functions is changed, the COM+ Class ID could change and the object safety script will not work, causing the BSTCustomValidation.dll validation component to not run."

The template worked just fine, assumingly not changing the COM+ Class ID. When I added a bunch of private methods, the COM+ Class ID seemed to change and failed the validation. But, when I created an interface and had the class inherit from it, it passed validation just fine, presumably because the Com Class ID was as same as the original template.

Why did adding private methods change the Com+ Class ID, but then adding the interface change it back.

Answer (score 1):

C# (or other CLR languages) generate CLSIDs for COM-visible objects in one of two ways:

1. You specify the CLSID explicitly using the [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute.aspx) attribute, or
2. The CLR runtime generates one for you based on the [type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) of the class.  I don't know the exact algorithm, except that it's not random (or else the CLSIDs would change from build to build).

So, adding private methods changed the type data for the class, and therefore changed the GUID; but being an interface apparently does not affect the GUID generation algorithm.

If you want to add private methods without having an interface, then get the current GUID (e.g., via reflection) and specify that GUID explicitly using the Guid attribute.

Comment: It wasn't until that comment that I realized (though, it's surprise) that just because an object has same name and same public methods they really are different types. kudos